# Why i am not able to capture screen shot of selectbox items using selenium-python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a select box on my page. I click on it to expand it and all values are displayed. Now i take screenshot, but in screenshot, select box is not expanded. Please check.

Code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from unittest import TestCase
import re
import time
import autoit

url="https://www.facebook.com"

class SprintTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(url)

    def test_offer_1(self):
        a=self.driver.find_element_by_id("day")
        a.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.save_screenshot("res.jpg")


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Image generated by my code:
[image]

Expected Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given situation, it is expected to behave in this way.
When you perform save_screenshot on driver object, the driver object is now busy getting the screenshot for you instead of keeping the select menu open.
One possible solution is that you launch the save_screenshot method in different thread.

Comment: So, this is limitation of selenium?

Comment: No, selenium is functioning as it is supposed to and in the correct manner.How can you expect a single object to perform two different task at the same time? you need to achieve this using thread.

Comment: Can you help me with code for using different thread. I tried to search, but no result. Just a basic idea would do.

Comment: After little investigation, it turns out that this is a limitation as far as I have looked into it(do not take my word on it - do some searches from your side as well) . https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/eWYRig7c1C4/azFDkLjWK8wJ

Comment: To overcome this limitation you can  use some python module seperately just to take screenshots like pyscreenshot.

Comment: Used pyscreenshot to serve my purpose.